# Implementing logger functionality without using new keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to implement logger.logerror functionality in user.js middleware.I want to implement that functionality by using functions only.

```
/* logger.js */   
    
     const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
        
            function Logger(){
                let logger=createLogger({
                    transports:
                        new transports.File({
                        level:'error',
                        filename:'error.log',
                        format:format.json(),
                    }),
        
             logError(err){
            logger.error(err);    
            }
        })
            }
        
        module.exports= Logger;


    
  
    /*user.js */
    exports.getUser=async(req,res)=>{
       
       const{name,age}=req.query;
            try{
                let where={};
                if(age){
                    where.age={$gte:(parseInt(req.query.age))}
                } 
                if(name){
                    where.name=req.query.name
                }
            const savedUser=await User.find(where)
                res.json(savedUser);
        }
        catch(err){
```

here I want to call the logger .So that it can return method, err, date.I want to call logger here so that it can show the errors.

```
  logger.logError(`function:controller.getUser, error:${err.toString()} -method: ${req.method}-date:${new Date(Date.now()).toUTCString()}`);
        res.status(500).json({message:err});
    }
 };
```

Comment: So export an instance of it....

Comment: I already have imported logger file in user

Comment: but you did not export an instance of it.

Comment: how will i,explain?

Comment: Something like `module.exports= new Logger();` might not be 100% right, not at my computer to test.

Comment: I have exported logger file,check

Comment: Thats the catch here.I dont want to use new keyword.I wanna do that by using functions only.

Comment: You code is rather weird since Logger does not actually return anything and is not a class. So the new stuff I recommended is not going to work since the Logger method is lacking things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228483/discussion-between-raj-rupam-and-epascarello).

Comment: i have implemented it by using new,i want to implement it by using functions

Comment: So something like `function Logger(){ let logger=createLogger(...); return logger; } module.exports= Logger();`

Comment: Its not working